# MediaPlayer stop audio sound C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying create a mediaplayer in C#. The wav file has 50 seconds. But, the media player created play the sound only 3 seconds and stop it. It don't play sound complete...

```
public void tocar(string caminho)
        {
            MediaPlayer myPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            myPlayer.Open(new System.Uri(caminho));         
            myPlayer.Play();

        }
        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
            tocar("C:/Natiruts.wav");
            //Play("C:/bit1.wav");

        }
```

Comment: Hmm, is there any error message somewhere?

Comment: No error message. List erro is empty...